# using variables to call variables

Tags: c#, variables, object, concatenation

hi how to I do the below?

```
int z = 1;
string one = "pc";
string two = z.ToString();
                    //what goes here
Console.Write("Host One:\tSent-{0}\tSuccess-{1}\tFail-{2}", xxxxx.numepings, pc1.numepings_s, pc1.numepings_f);
Console.WriteLine();
```

so in my code `pc1` is an instance of an object, what can i use in the line `//what goes here` and then in place of the `xxxxx` so that I can call the instance from the concanatated string variable `pc` and `int 1` ??

Comment: _"pc1" is an instance of an object_ - No, instances do not have names. `pc1` is a reference variable that happens to point to a particular instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally don't understand your question.  What are you trying to achieve here, and why?  What have the variables `z`, `one` and `two` got to do with anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you don't. You *can* potentially use reflection, but it's a bad idea. Instead, you should use a *collection* whenever you want to store references to multiple objects and address them by some sort of key (whether that's an index, a name, whatever).

So instead of having:

```
Foo pc0;
Foo pc1;
Foo pc2;
...
```

You would have:

```
List<Foo> pcs;
...
Foo pc = pcs[z];
```

Comment: mmmm I remember some thing like this in VBA, but that was a while ago, need to go take a look.

Comment: And if you want to access the objects by a string label/tag instead of an index, use a Dictionary instead of a List.

Comment: @DevilWAH: Yes, you may well be able to do it from VBA - that doesn't mean you *should*, or that you can use the same idiom in C#.

Comment: I mean the method of using a list to hold the refrences :) I jsut forgot I had done it before

Comment: @DevilWAH: Ah, I see. Yes, I'd certainly expect that to be possible in VBA too :)

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fce0hc8.aspx

```
// Create an instance of the SomeType class that is defined in this 
// assembly.
var oh = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase, one + z /* as a  full type name */);

// Call an instance method defined by the SomeType type using this object.
dynamic st = oh.Unwrap();

st.DoSomething(5);
```

You can do something like this to create an object, from it's string name - but you can't cast it to a particular type without issues.

You can cheat, and use `dynamic` though.

Edit: sorry, this wasn't quite right originally - and I have fixed my example.

Comment: While this answers the literal question posted, I think this is bad advice to give.

Comment: I see that this might not be the best answer, given Jons reply - but it is still an answer to the question asked, explicitly.

Comment: Hah - agreed. :) - But it may come in handy for someone searching for an answer to a similar issue, that can't benefit from the above advice.